# Why the docker node container doesn't find local files in the docker volume?

Tags: docker

I try to run a web app from local files in a node container. To do so, using PowerShell, I go to the app root folder and I run

```
PS C:\my_local_dir> docker run -p 8080:4200 -v ${pwd}:/www -w "/www" node npm start
```

and this is the output I get:

```
npm ERR! path /www/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/www/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I can confirm that the file *package.json* is present, and that running `npm start` in this folder works.

Inspecting the container with `docker inspect`:

```
(...)
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/host_mnt/c/my_local_dir",
            "Destination": "/www",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
(...)
```

What's wrong in my command ?

By the way I got the command from [this PluralSight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=docker-web-development&author=dan-wahlin&name=docker-web-development-m4&clip=4&mode=live)

Comment: Can you do `docker run -v ${pwd}:/www -w "/www" node ls`

Comment: @grapes It only returns _package-lock.json_, probably coming from a previous `npm install` I tried to run earlier to fix the issue, unsuccesfully.

Comment: Okay, and what about  `dir` on your **host** machine right before starting docker?

Comment: It lists all the files at the root directory of my app, including _package.json_.

Comment: Try without `PS`. `docker run -p 8080:4200 -v c:\my_local_dir:/www -w "/www" node ls && npm start`

Comment: How does your Dockerfile looks like? did you copy all files into the container?

Comment: @Igor There is no custom Dockerfile, the image is the official node image.

Comment: @grapes No change (sorry I reacted too fast in a previous comment, it worked because I unwillingly started the app locally, not in the container)